# symfony 3 install gedmo timestamp 0000:00:00

Tags: symfony

i follow this tutorial to have create and update field in my entity

[Gedmo tutorial](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/symfony2.md)

After 
config.yml

```
   orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
                translatable:
                    type: annotation
                    alias: Gedmo
                    prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                    # make sure vendor library location is correct
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity/MappedSuperclass"
                loggable:
                    type: annotation
                    alias: Gedmo
                    prefix: Gedmo\Loggable\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity"
                tree:
                    type: annotation
                    alias: Gedmo
                    prefix: Gedmo\Tree\Entity
                    dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity"
```

My mapping info :

```
    [OK]   Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractPersonalTranslation
[OK]   Gedmo\Translatable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractTranslation
[OK]   Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractLogEntry
[OK]   Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry
[OK]   Gedmo\Tree\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractClosure
```

After i Create the doctrine_extensions.yml file

```
services:
    # KernelRequest listener
    extension.listener:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Listener\DoctrineExtensionListener
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ "@service_container" ] ]
        tags:
            # translatable sets locale after router processing
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onLateKernelRequest, priority: -10 }
            # loggable hooks user username if one is in security context
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
            # translatable sets locale such as default application locale before command execute
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.command, method: onConsoleCommand, priority: -10 }



# Doctrine Extension listeners to handle behaviors
gedmo.listener.tree:
    class: Gedmo\Tree\TreeListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]

gedmo.listener.translatable:
    class: Gedmo\Translatable\TranslatableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]
        - [ setDefaultLocale, [ %locale% ] ]
        - [ setTranslationFallback, [ false ] ]

gedmo.listener.timestampable:
    class: Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]

gedmo.listener.sluggable:
    class: Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]

gedmo.listener.sortable:
    class: Gedmo\Sortable\SortableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]

gedmo.listener.loggable:
    class: Gedmo\Loggable\LoggableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]

gedmo.listener.blameable:
    class: Gedmo\Blameable\BlameableListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_subscriber, connection: default }
    calls:
        - [ setAnnotationReader, [ "@annotation_reader" ] ]            
        - [ setUserValue, [ "@security.token_storage" ] ]
```

and i put in my config file

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: doctrine_extensions.yml }
```

i create also a

```
<?php
// file: src/AppBundle/Listener/DoctrineExtensionListener.php
namespace AppBundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;

class DoctrineExtensionListener implements ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onLateKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $translatable = $this->container->get('gedmo.listener.translatable');
        $translatable->setTranslatableLocale($event->getRequest()->getLocale());
    }

    public function onConsoleCommand()
    {
        $this->container->get('gedmo.listener.translatable')
            ->setTranslatableLocale($this->container->get('translator')->getLocale());
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if (Kernel::MAJOR_VERSION == 2 && Kernel::MINOR_VERSION < 6) {
            $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context', ContainerInterface::NULL_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE);
            if (null !== $securityContext && null !== $securityContext->getToken() && $securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
                $loggable = $this->container->get('gedmo.listener.loggable');
                $loggable->setUsername($securityContext->getToken()->getUsername());
            }
        }
        else {
            $tokenStorage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();
            $authorizationChecker = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');
            if (null !== $tokenStorage && $authorizationChecker->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
                $loggable = $this->container->get('gedmo.listener.loggable');
                $loggable->setUsername($tokenStorage->getUser());
                $blameable = $this->container->get('gedmo.listener.blameable');
                $blameable->setUserValue($tokenStorage->getUser());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the end i put in my entity :

```
Use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;

....
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $created;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="changed", type="datetime")
     */
    private $changed;
```

and work but  in my sql database when i see the entity created date is:

0000-00-00 00:00:00

I don't understand Why don't take the current date?

Comment: Update your question with current configuration and rephrase it so that there was a goal we could help you achieve. 'Can help me??' is not a way to ask question on stackoverflow. See this page for more info https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: when you update the entity , does "changed" field take o correct date ?

Comment: always 0000:00:00 ..  i resolve it in another way  :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403569/how-to-set-created-and-updated-date-in-symfony2